# What data structure could this be?

Tags: data-structures, amortized-analysis

I have the following question that I haven't been able to answer:
design a data structure that support the following features:

Insertion will be made to the first empty slot

Access to an object with index i will be made in O(1) time

Doesnt need to support extraction

The goal is to decrease to minimum the amount of unused memory, and the complexity of the insertion.

Show that for a K amount of unused memory the complexity of insertion is O(n/k) in amortized analysis.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: A chained scattered hash table, perhaps?

Comment: I don't know this sort of ds can you maybe elaborate?

Comment: O(1)? Seriously a constant? So it doesn't matter if I have one element or a trillion, it takes the same amount of time to fetch any given one?

Comment: Well that is the question, why is it so surprising? a simple array supports this feature.

Comment: Well I don't think Chained Scatter Table is the answer for two reasons:
a. It won't support an infinite insertions
b. the access  is not in O(1) time
I really don't know this data structure too well, am I wrong?